# Angular 6 ng-select2 populate from api

Tags: angular, angular6, jquery-select2, angular-observable

i have this json response from api:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Juan",
    "edad": 20
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "nombre": "Pepe",
    "edad": 26
},
...
]
```

I want to populate my select2 (using lib ng-select2) with this response, but showing nombre and edad, e.g:  Juan - 20

I receive the response correctly but cannot  attach and show it in select2, (I can repoduce the examples of this lib correctly but this are with hardcoded data).

this is my attempt. in my persons.service

```
getPersons(): Observable<Array<Select2OptionData>> {
return this.http.get<Array<Select2OptionData>>(this.API_URL);           
}
```

persons.component.ts

```
export class PersonsComponent implements OnInit {

 public exampleData: Array<Select2OptionData>;

  constructor(public  personsService:  PersonsService) {}

 ngOnInit() { this.getPersons}

 getPersons(): void {
   this.personsService.getPersons().subscribe(
   persons => {this.exampleData = persons; 
               console.log(persons);} // the information shows correctly in console.
)
}
```

persons.component.html

```
<ng-select2 [data]="exampleData"
        [(ngModel)]="value">
</ng-select2>
```

result: the select2 shows 2 empty rows but no the information.
I know that the problems is with the interface Select2OptionData (it uses id, text), but I am new at angular , so how can I parse or adapt my response to Select2OptionData? should I do it in the service or in the component.ts?? hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

[ng-select2's `[data]` attribute expects a `Select2Data` instance](https://github.com/Harvest-Dev/ng-select2#properties-and-events-of-the-component).

Your service should probably return something that isn't related to Select2 at all, like a `Person[]` array where you have defined the `Person` as an interface with those attributes:

```
interface Person {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  edad: number;
}
```

Then, on component side, you can use rxjs' `map` operator, like this:

```
this.personsService.getPersons().pipe(
  map((persons: Person[]) => persons.map((person: Person) => ({label: person.name, value: person.id})))
).subscribe((personsData: Select2Data) => {
  this.exampleData = personsData;
});
```

and change your component's property to the right type:

```
public exampleData: Select2Data;
```

Comment: but exampleData : Select2Data will work as an array? cause the response has 2 or more persons

Comment: @matQ It's defined as `type Select2Data = (Select2Group | Select2Option)[];`, so it's an array behind the scenes. I didn't test this code so some things might be wrong, but it should be close to what you need (edit: check my last edit for a few fixes here and there).